# Django Ratelimiting

Tags: django

Im using the Django ratelimiting http://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/v0.3.0/index.html
In dev everything works fine.

However in prod when using virtual environments it just doesnt work. Either the ratelimiting (i.e the view) doesnt kick in when it should or it just doesnt kick in at all.
The main difference between the 2 environments is I have my settings file split. i.e

```
webtools_django15/
|-- __init__.py
|-- myapp
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- myapp.wsgi
|   |-- myapp_settings.py
|   |-- myapp_settings.pyc
|   |-- myapp_urls.py
|   |-- forms.py
|   |-- forms.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- views.py-bak
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- manage.py
|-- modules
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- dnslookup.py
|-- static
|   ! omitted !
|-- templates
|   ! omitted !
`-- webtools_django15
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- settings.py
    |-- settings.py-bak
    |-- settings.pyc
    `-- urls.py
```

**VIEW**

```
@ratelimit(rate="5/s", method="POST", block=True)
@ratelimit(ip=True, rate="3/s", method="POST", block=True)
def report_ajax(request):
   ....
```

**MYAPP.SETTINGS.PY**

```
from settings import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

SITE_ID = 1

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.myapp_urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        "/opt/django/webtools_django15/templates"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrapform',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    }
}

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/opt/django/webtools_django15/static/',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

RATELIMIT_ENABLE = True
RATELIMIT_VIEW = "myapp.views.ratelimited"


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'ratelimit.middleware.RatelimitMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but what is your production environment? Apache, wsgi, nginx, gunicorn, etc?

Comment: apache, wgsi daemon, and virtual environments....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this app uses your configured `cache` to keep the counts for rate limiting users.  I'm guessing you have a variance in your cache environment between development and production.

Your settings don't mention any cache configuration, so you're likely inheriting the [django defaults](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches), which is a local memory cache.

When you run in a production environment like apache or wsgi containers like unicorn or uwsgi, they spawn multiple processes to server requests in parallel.  I local memory cache is not shared between those processes, so your counts are not properly tracked.

Switch to a cache like memcache or redis to keep these counts persistent between your requests processes.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a simple django database for the cache and it worked a treat. Found here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#database-caching

Comment: That will work, but it will slow you down a bit since you're both reading and writing to your SQL database with every request (to update the counts).  I'm assuming you're using rate-limiting cause you're trying to prevent your clients from overloading your system, so keep in mind that other caches (like memcache or redis) would be much faster.

Comment: Ok thanks, its a very small site (www.dnsdonkey.co.uk), more of a project really so it should be too much of an issue....